# DockingPanels in Mobile View

Tags: autodesk-forge

How does the DockingPanels work in a mobile view. These Panel seems to have fixed sizes and even the drag option doesn't work in Mobile view. Please suggest the proper implementation for the inbuilt and custom docking panels within Viewer.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is on your side, but it seems to work fine on my side. I tried this [sample](https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/) and the Model Browser on my iPhone - I could move the Model Browser Panel and Resize it without any issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am using Fabric React Panel for the viewer. In normal web view it works fine, but in mobile all the docking models get struck and doesn't move.